# Error creating bean with name 'dao'

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, jakarta-ee, jpa

i dont know ahy i got this error when i wanna test my app using spring beans this the main test :
public class Test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context=
    new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]  
    {"applicationContext.xml"});
    IBanqueMetier metier=(IBanqueMetier) context.getBean("metier");
    metier.addClient(new Client("C1", "AD1"));
    metier.addClient(new Client("C2", "AD2"));
}
```

and this the 1rst error :

```
Exception in thread   "main"org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
      Error creating bean with name 'dao': Injection of persistence dependencies

failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: org.gestion.bp.entities.Compte.employe
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:342)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
```

Comment: You mean the error message "Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a OneToMany, ManyToMany or CollectionOfElements: org.gestion.bp.entities.Compte.employe" ? And ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Spring exceptions, it's important that you read the whole message up to the very end. I usually split the message into several lines to make it more readable:

```
Exception in thread   "main"org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'dao': Injection of persistence dependencies failed;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]:
Invocation of init method failed;
nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException:
Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements:
org.gestion.bp.entities.Compte.employe
```

As you can see, you made an error in the definition of the field `org.gestion.bp.entities.Compte.employe`